# Detect clusters from graph

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, matplotlib

I have a csv with near about 156 columns. I want to plot the Scatter graph with one of the columns as X axis and another one as Y axis. By making combinations of 150 columns i will be generating 11K graphs. Now I have to go through each graph to see is there distinguishable clusters in graph.but to go with visual route it will take whole lot of time.and in feature if graph changes i have to repeat the work. So I am looking for solution where i can detect which graph has clusters.

I will provide one of the sample graph generated by using python matplot library.

[image: Image link here]

I will also sharing some of the column structure which i am having.

```
  col1           col2           col3           col4           col5
  0.05414        0.0027070      0.012994       0.0508931      0.042772063
  0.00155        0.0001942      0.000388       0.0120453      0.0069943
```

I am intermediate at Python-2.7

Comment: 1) Clustering is a very large and active area of research. See the tag for relevant questions on this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering?sort=votes . 2) Have you considered dimension reduction techniques? 3) If you don't want to reduce the dimensionality, do you need to find clusters in 2 dimensions? You could attempt to search for clusters in higher-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

> So i am looking for solution where i can detect which graph has clusters.

The question is not clearly defined. I would ask OP some questions to help OP to clarify.

- What is the definition of "cluster"? For example, for the plot you pasted, how many clusters are there?
- Cluster has little thing to do with graph. No matter we plot it or not, the cluster always exists (if we define it properly). So, is your question trying to ask can we detect clusters on 2D marginal distribution of the data?
- Please note that, the clusters on marginal distribution may not mean anything. Do you want clusters on data, or only on marginal distribution?

Comment: basically I have 4 Class in my dataset. I have plotted it by different colors for classes.Suppose I have x and y values of each class. Is there any mathematical method to find that data  of class should be diffentiable from other class.

Comment: I have such 150 of x and y columns. By this It will produce 11350 graphs.instead of looking manually I want to calculate it mathematically.